# How does one use the format() method in python to pad numbers after the E exponent with zeros?

Tags: python-2.7, string.format

I have managed to almost get my number output formatted to exactly what I need after reading some documentation on .format, and developing this code:

```
timepoint = 6
strTimepoint = "{:1.7E}".format(timepoint)
```

whereby printing strTimepoint will issue this:

```
# with timepoint = 6
>>6.0000000E+00
# with timepoint = 12
>>1.2000000E+01
```

and so on.

The only thing I need to do to make this the string I need is for the exponent digits to be padded with zeros to be three digits, hence:

```
# timepoint = 6
>>6.0000000E+000
# timepoint = 12 
>>1.2000000E+001
```

I cannot simply pad with a zero after the fact, as it needs to be adaptive to numbers requiring higher than single digit exponents.
I was not able to find documentation on this, so any help on this topic is of help, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that it's just not possible with single [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) call.

It won't be as pretty, but you can simply add another one:

```
# Regular Python's scientific notation, split up to coefficient and exponent.
x, e = "{:1.7E}".format(timepoint).split("E")

# Format again: coefficient first, then sign, then padded "sign-less" exponent.
strTimepoint = "{}E{}{:0>3}".format(x, e[0], e[1:])
```

Wrapping it all in a function is, of course, strongly encouraged (adjust the name to your needs):

```
def foo(timepoint):
    # Regular Python's scientific notation, split up to coefficient and
    # exponent.
    x, e = "{:1.7E}".format(timepoint).split("E")

    # Format again: coefficient first, then sign, then padded "sign-less"
    # exponent.
    return "{}E{}{:0>3}".format(x, e[0], e[1:])


foo(6)  # '6.0000000E+000'
foo(12)  # '1.2000000E+001'
foo(1e123)  # '1.0000000E+123'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could insert the 0 after the fact with `re.sub`, but it would have the effect of lengthening the string by one character in the case that the substitution occurs:

```
>>> re.compile("(E[-+])(\d\d)$").sub(r'\g<1>0\2',"{:7.1E}".format(6E19))
'6.0E+019'
```

With the 7.1 format, that's not a problem because if the exponent had three digits, the minimum field length would be 8:

```
>>> re.compile("(E[-+])(\d\d)$").sub(r'\g<1>0\2',"{:7.1E}".format(6E190))
'6.0E+190'
```

But in general, it could produce misalignments.

(Of course, in real code, you'd only compile that regex once, rather than every time you do the conversion.)